# syntax for advanced custom fields in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax

I am trying to display a field, but it shows the value fine, but OUTSIDE of the  tags?!??!

```
echo '<h2>'. the_field('where') .'</h2>';
```

Output =

```
"London"
<h2></h2>
```

Should be =

```
<h2>London</h2>
```

Comment: you are missing something you show in h3 tags but you want h2 tags? i don't understand

Comment: the_field function should return the value not echo it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<h2><?php the_field('where'); ?></h2>
```

**Explanation:**

You code has the output it has because of how `echo` works. It first generates the whole string (running the functions), and then it renders the output. So, if the function `the_field` has output, it will generate what you see.

Basically your code is equivalent to:

```
$title = '<h3>'. the_field('where') .'</h3>';
echo $title;
```

**Example:**

```
function test() {
    echo '1';
    return '2';
}
echo 'PRE - ' . test() . ' - POST';
```

And here is the result:

```
$ php test.php
1PRE - 2 - POST
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you have a function like this:

```
function  the_field($text){
 echo $text;
}
echo '<h3>'. the_field('where') .'</h3>';
```

Change your function to:

```
function  the_field($text){
 return $text;
}
echo '<h3>'. the_field('where') .'</h3>';
```

Why? Because PHP executes the function before printing output of the echo.

Comment: or he echos in the function with h2 tags and tries to exho with h3 again?